# azure sql server database connection errors

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am pretty new to all the azure thing, till now my project was connected to localhost database.
i managed to create server in azure and uploaded my database to that server, i opened the access for my IP and everything was fine till i tried to use my website with functions that use the database (Sign up).

First, i got an error from the browser says:
`Login failed for user '{user}'`. so i added the server name to the user name like `user@server_name`. that solved this error.

After this i tried again and another error came up from the browser `Cannot open server "server_name}" requested by the login.  The login failed.`

I have no idea why the login is failing... when i try to log in to the data base from SSMS i have no problems, i have put the same credentials for login in the `connectionString` `web.config` file, so i have no idea what the problem is.

Here is my `connectionString`:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myapp"
  connectionString="Server=tcp:myapp.database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=myapp.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=myapp;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={XXXX};Password={XXXXXX};Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Please help.

Comment: You should post your connection string, obscuring any sensitive info.

Comment: i edited my `connectionString`, thanks

Comment: Have you configured the firewall for your Azure SQL Server?

Comment: Could it be that your app is using a different deploy configuration when you release it to Azure, a transformation file such as web.config.release?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead.

> Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase; User
>   ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
>   Encrypt=True;

Comment: that solved the error and i manage to sign up, but only when i access my website locally, when i try to do the same from after running the website from the server, it says another error `No connection string named 'myDataBase' could be found in the application config file.` why locally all DB methods are working but from the server no? (before your solution, even locally it did not work)

Answer (score 0):

That solved my problem:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="DB_Name"
      connectionString="Server=server_name,1433;Database=DB_Name;User ID=user_name;Password=user_password"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Now everything work locally and from the server too